# restructure table - convert results in column to header to table in C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, datatable

I'm trying to find a way to restructure the results of an SQL query loaded into a c# dataTable. I need to swap the dynamic results of column X0 with the header row X1-4.
before:

```
X0  | X1 | X2 | X3 | X4
_______________________
Y1  |  X | X  | X  | x
Y2  |  X | X  | X  | x
Y3  |  X | X  | X  | X
```

After:

```
 O  | Y1 | Y2 | Y3 | 
____________________
X1  |  X | X  | X  |
X2  |  X | X  | X  |
X3  |  X | X  | X  | 
X4  |  X | X  | X  |
```

I have some code that serilizes the table into a JSON object but I need to modify it to give me the output above.
JSON serializer code:

```
   foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }

        return jss.Serialize(rows);
    }
```

Any ideas or code submissions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is the purpose of pivoting the output in c#? If you are getting the data from SQL Server, you could use `pivot` in tsql to achieve the desired result.

Comment: thanks, I'm new to programming and the PIVOT function is a new concept for me. I'll do some research and see what I can come up with.